# Is Kara (SuperGirl) natural born?

Tags: supergirl, superman

We learn that Kal-El is a rare [natural born](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/why-didnt-jor-el-and-lara-leave-krypton-with-their-son) Kryptonian.

What about Kara?

I'm not familiar enough with the continuities to specify, but please use the same continuity that explains Kal-El's birth.

Comment: Superman in the tv show "Supergirl" isn't natural born (There's no relation between the show and the Superman movies)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the CBS TV show, *Supergirl*, we have no evidence that Kryptonians are anything but natural born. The only knowledge we have about their births is that twins are extremely rare, making Alura and Astra an oddity. However, even this seems to suggest natural births.

Only in the Zack Snyder DC cinematic movies, *Man of Steel*, *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice* and the upcoming related releases, does the idea that Kryptonians don't give birth, but rather clone or manufacturer themselves, exist.

Both versions of Krypton, *Supergirl's* and *Man of Steel's* are completely separate continuities.

Comment: Just like tvs Flash is different from movie Flash.